# MySQL update table on both match and no match

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table of statistics, and want to set a column flag if rows match a certain criteria.  I also want to clear the column flag if the criteria doesn't match.  I figured out the first part, but I'm not sure how to clear the flag.

```
UPDATE my_table
JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE criteria > "5"
) a
ON my_table.id=a.id
SET flag="1";
```

Basically, I want to add something like `ELSE flag="0"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET flag=IF(criteria > "5", "1", "0")
;
```